# In-Market Segments data in a real time for anonymous users via GA API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

Is there an option to read the In-Market Segments data in a real-time for anonymous users via GA API?

My goal is to target new users on the first-page view using the In-Market Segments data and pass it to my personalization tool in order to deliver personalized content. Thanks!

Comment: The GA API doesn't allow you to find which segment a user belongs to in real-time. The workaround would be to store user data in a cookie, and pass that information through to your personalization tool.

Comment: Thanks, @vinoaj but the missing part for me is where I get the data? Let's say I have a segment for Travel. Once the anonymous user arrives to my website I want to be able to send an event/store the information in the cookie/etc... to the personalization tool and mark the user.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed the part where you're focused on in-market segments specifically. This you can't determine as GA doesn't revel that informaton on a per-user basis with its cookies. This is for privacy purposes.